# Postgis installation

Tags: postgis, installation, debian

I am installing Postgis on my Debian server, following these instructions:

http://postgis.net/install/ (Ubuntu / Debian)

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

However, after following the instructions it looks  like I have installed PostGres (9.4), but no PostGIS.

Do I have to install something more that was omitted in the instructions?

Can I somehow add PostGIS as a PostGres Plugin / Extension?

Comment: Create extension postgis;

Comment: `FEHLER:  konnte Erweiterungskontrolldatei „/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension/postgis.control“ nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden`

Comment: means something like: `ERROR: could not open Extension control file "$PATH": File or Directory not found`

Answer (score 6):

I did an extensive blog post on installing PostgreSQL 9.3/PostGIS 2.1 a few months ago at http://geospatial.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2014/10/25/installing-postgresqlpostgis-on-linux-mint-17/. It's not immediately clear to me what went wrong in your case, because you haven't really described what you did. In particular, the PostGIS installation instructions you link to describe compiling from source, as well as using the official repositories, and you don't say what you did. The fact that you are getting the message that `postgis.control` is missing when you try `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` seems to imply that you have not successfully installed the PostGIS package. You could try

```
dpkg-query -l postgis
```

and see if it returns

```
ii  postgis        2.1.3+dfsg-3 i386         Geographic objects support for Po
```

or any other version.

If PostGIS is not in fact installed you can install from the PostgreSQL repository, which, if you have followed the directions at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt, is the one I believe you are using.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1
```

Note that

```
sudo apt-get install postgis
```

should also work, but I'm not which version of PostGIS it will attempt to install since you are connected to both PostgreSQL and Ubuntu repositories, and the Ubuntu repository is still only up to PostgreSQL 9.3. So there might be a dependency issue there, but I'm not going to attempt to confirm that on my system.

Once this is installed (you can confirm by looking for `/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension/postgis.control`, the file that showed as missing before), you can proceed by logging on to PostgreSQL with a SUPERUSER account, connecting to your database (*not* the postgres database, your actual data database) and

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
```

Note that `fuzzystrmatch` (which is useful for the geocoder) requires the `postgresql-contrib` package.

I'm glossing over a lot here, but it's possible that I haven't correctly identified the problem, so I don't want to expand on this until I know we're on the right track. Also, please refer to my blog post above for more detail.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1` => ` Paket postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 kann nicht gefunden werden
E: Mittels regulärem Ausdruck »postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1« konnte kein Paket gefunden werden` (something like `Package could not been found`)

Comment: `dpkg-query -l postgis` =>  `........ ii  postgis                                       1.5.1-5                                       geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- common files`

Comment: but: `Create extension postgis;` within a database => `FEHLER: konnte Erweiterungskontrolldatei „/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension/postgis.control“ nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden`

Comment: means something like: `ERROR: could not open Extension control file "$PATH": File or Directory not found`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install postgis` worked, by the way, but it does not seem to  be connected to PostGres

Comment: OK, you have PostGIS 1.5 installed which *cannot* be loaded using the PostgreSQL extension framework. You need PosGIS 2.0+. Did you install PostGIS *before* adding the PostgreSQL apt repository? Because wheezy has PostGIS 1.5 but doesn't even have PostgreSQL 9.4, which you managed to install. But the PostgreSQL repository has every version of PostgreSQL you could want, but *doesn't* have PostGIS <2.0. Which version of Debian are you using? Print results of `apt-cache search --names-only 'postgis'` to see which PostGIS versions you have available.

Comment: Basically, if PostGIS 2.0+ is available, you need to `sudo apt-get purge postgis-1.5` followed by installing the correct version. `postgis` is a metapackage which depends on a specific version. It looks like the PostgreSQL repository doesn't provide the `postgis` metapackage, so since you did `sudo apt-get install postgis`, that probably found the `postgis` metapackage in your Debian version (wheezy?) which depends on `postgis-1.5`, and installed that instead of 2.0 or 2.1. That's possibly how you ended up with PostgreSQL 9.4 but PostGIS 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

You are installing from apt or compiling from source?

You can try:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

This will reload a few library links. This is mostly likely to happen if you installed from source.

If that still doesn't work, create a file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ names geos.conf and add this content to the file: /usr/local/lib (this is the address where your geos, gdal, etc, libraries are installed. if they are in a different location, change the /usr/local/lib to reflected the directory accondingly). After that, do another sudo ldconfig and try again.

Another idea: are you installing the extension using the postgres user on operation system? If not, try to use the postgres user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the PostGIS extension as well, it doesn't install by default by just installing PostgreSQL.

instructions here:

http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt

You'll have to change a bit for 9.4